# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on localhost (10061)

Tags: mysql

I installed  MySQL on Microsoft Windows 8 Using a noinstall Zip Archive. But when I tested by executing the following commands on windows prompt, the above error showed up.

```
C:\> "C:\MySQL\bin\mysqlshow" 

C:\> "C:\MySQL\bin\mysql" test
```

Comment: Sounds like the MySQL service isn't running. Have you verified it's started?

Comment: I just took the easy route and reinstall MySQL. Worked after that

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You don't need to restart your windows. The easiest way to achieve this is

1. Go to `<Extracted folder location>/bin/`
2. Run `mysqld` (service)
3. close the cmd prompt
4. Run `mysql.exe` or the better way to do is add the location to PATH environment Variable

Comment: My problem was that the mysql service wasn't running. Whatever a restart solved my problem.

Comment: @Imray: you can see /bin in your installation directory

Comment: @CodyBugstein where ever you installed your mysql folder. Usually in the C:/ (for windows)

Comment: I faced https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504580/cant-create-test-file-lower-test-start-server-mysql after the above issue was solved

Answer (score 32):

Go to Run type `services.msc`. Check whether MySQL services is running or not. If not, start it manually. Once it started, type `mysqlshow` to test the service.

Comment: mysql service was down. Upon starting, it resolved the issue

Comment: there is no mysql named service in list of services.msc

Answer (score 19):

1. Go to bin directory copy the path and set it as a environment variable.
2. Run the command prompt as admin and cd to bin directory.
3. Run command : `mysqld –install`
4. Now the services are successfully installed
5. Start the service in service windows of os
6. Type `mysql` and go

Comment: Nice! only thing I had to do extra was run: "net start mysql" after step 4. May be that's what you are doing manually in step 5?

Comment: so cute! I was hopeless deactivating UAC, firewall, restarting... but when I install service it works great! thanks that's really great!

Comment: I also had to run 'net start mysql' to start MySQL service @DamodarBashyal Thank you! Please edit step 5 to say this as it is now clear

Comment: In my special case, I was getting **"File not found"** error (when trying to start the service). The problem was from the incorrect executable path that was assigned to the service by default (using `mysqld --install`). So I changed it to correct one (`C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld`) in Windows Registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MySQL`).

Answer (score 17):

Though it is an old question, I am adding my answer in it, because the solution that worked for me on Windows 7 as an admin user, is missing in the answers' list. Though my solution is for installed MySQL, I am putting it for those who search for a solution for this error message. Here it is:

1. Click on the Windows 7 start button and type `taskmgr` in the search bar
2. Right click on the taskmgr program icon and select `Run as administrator`
3. In the Task Manager window, go to the `Services` tab
4. Right click on the `MySQL` service and click `Start Service`

[image: Step 1 and 2][image: Step 3 and 4]

Comment: I don't really know how this worked, but it worked on Windows 10 also if anyone wonders

Answer (score 13):

The solution that worked for me is:

1. Downloaded mysql-8.0.22-winx64.zip file
2. Extracted the zip file
3. Moved the extracted folder to C:/Program Files
4. Opened cmd.exe as admin
5. Navigated to the directory `cd C:\Program Files\mysql-8.0.22\mysql-8.0.22-winx64\bin`
6. `mysqld -install` (Service successfully installed)
7. `mysqld --initialize` (no prompt)
8. Opened services.msc
9. Found MySQL
10. Right-click and start

Answer (score 6):

Go to Run type `services.msc`. Check whether `MySQL` services is running or not. If not, start it manually.

Answer (score 5):

1. Run your cmd as administrator.
2. What you will see is like this:

   ```
   c:\windows\system32>
   ```
3. Go to your bin location by using cd..
   like `C:\mysql\bin` (my location of bin in my computer is what you are seeing so chose yours correctly)
4. Run:

   ```
   $ C:\mysql\bin>mysql --install

   Service successfully installed.
   ```
5. Then run:

   ```
   $ C:\mysql\bin>NET START MySql

   The MySql service is starting
   The MySql service was started successfully
   ```
6. Then the last step is running:

   ```
   C:\mysql\bin>mysql -u root - p admin
   ```

   It will ask for password don't enter anything first time
   because it will use blank, and just press enter you are done.

And later you can set password too.

Answer (score 5):

I was stuck on this same issue for what felt like an eternity.

My problem was: I was running mysql from MAMP on port 8889, but when trying to connect to mysql from my command line, it was expecting port 3306. I was running out of ideas, so I tried:

`mysql --port 8889`

and happiness ensued:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.6.34-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: what is MAMP ? can you clarify

Answer (score 5):

Had this issue in Windows 10 and MySQL 8. Resolved by following steps:
Searchbar(bottom left) > Task Manager > Run as administrator > Services > MySQL80

Answer (score 4):

I have a windows 8.1 machine and mysql was not running at all even after trying to start mysqld with no error logs. This solution worked for me:

1. start cmd in admin mode
2. type in "net start mysql"
3. close current cmd window and open new cmd window
4. type in "mysql"

The mysqld service should now be available.

Answer (score 3):

Well that could have some reasons.

THe first one is that the MySQL server/service not started.

If he is started you should check out the logfiles, and make sure there are no problems.

You could also uninstall the MySQL service and install XAMPP.
With XAMPP it is easier to manage this services.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I found the silly solution myself. The system needed to restart. I will be trying XAMPP surely.

Comment: I'm sorry as i added the answer myself.

Answer (score 3):

Despite that my server was running, I had the same problem.
I found out that it was the port. So you need to specify the port:

```
mysql -u user -p --port 0000
```

The port on your machine may be different. To find out on which port mysql is running open the mysql ini file and look for `port=`. A port often used is `3306`.

Example how to log on to mysql

```
mysql -u root -p --port 3306
```

Answer (score 2):

Test if the server is running. You can use netstat for this. See https://serverfault.com/questions/260239/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-through-port-3306

If it is running, it may be the firewall. You can turn that off to test if that is the problem.

See the following manual to install Mysql as a service: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-start-service.html

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I found the silly solution myself. The system needed to restart.I would be considering your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Executing the `mysqld` command can solve your problem.
My SQL version is 5.7.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to ensure the port number on which the server is running. Then you can run

`mysql -u username -p --port portNumber`
on the command line

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the no install zip, you need to execute `mysqld.exe` first to start the service, and then execute `mysql.exe` to open your connection.

The no install is nice, but if you intend to do any serious work with MySQL, you may want to consider either using the MSI to do a proper installation, or if you're doing web development work give XAMPP a try.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I found the silly solution myself. The system needed to restart.

Answer (score 1):

Check Mysqld.exe file is in your bin folder. if it is not there , just copy that file from any other computer and paste it on your bin folder.Just double click. Then run mysql.its solved

Answer (score 1):

This error is flashed when we are trying to open mysql with out stating the service.

1. Open cmd prompt
   to start the service type

   ```
   mysqld --console
   ```

   This will start the mysql service
   [image]
2. Don't close this cmd prompt and open a new cmd prompt and
   type

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   ```

   Then enter ur password
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your mysql is running in default port (3306) , if you are running mysql with different port (for example: 3307), you must specified the port number while connecting to the server.

If your port is different than default port, then try with this command.

```
mysql -u <username> -p --port<port number>
```

For eg:

```
mysql -u root -p --port 3307
```

Answer (score 1):

Go and search **Services** in Windows

Now search **Mysql**. Right Click on it. By Default it's startup type will be 'Automatic'. Click on Properties on right clicked menu.
You will find startup type **Switch it to -> Manual** So that We can start and stop by our choice.

Now Get Back and Right Click to Mysql on Services and Click Start.

Now Mysql has started successfully

To get started
Start **Mysql Shell**
& type command

```
shell.connect({host: 'localhost',user: 'root'})
```

Now type password

To type sql commands:-

```
/sql
```

[image]

Comment: i did that and same error i got.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried all of the answers above (and some from other websites). In the end, my issue was that my cache wasn't configured. I found that info in my error log and fixed it by changing the line in the file:

C:\MAMP\bin\apache\conf\extra\http-ssl.conf

There I removed the double quotes from the line:

SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:/some/example/path/ssl_scache(512000)"

to:

SSLSessionCache        shmcb:/some/example/path/ssl_scache(512000)

and saved with Ctrl+S and closed the file.

Here's the link that helped me: 
https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/SSLSessionCache

Comment: How apache cache is related to mysql stand alone installation and startup?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem couple of times and each time the reason was different:

- The solution that worked first time was that by "Abhishek Oza" which is same as that of "amey91" (see above)
- The second time, my server was on a different port number than the default one(3036),so i was not able to connect.So I had to specify
  the port number explicitly for making the connection which you can do
  simply by writing: "**mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8081(specify your
  port number here) mysql -u root -p**"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, which was a manual install using the .zip file.
I solved this by specifying the nonstandard MySQL and Data install locations in a my.ini.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-create-option-file.html

Then I needed to run the data directory initialisation commands:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html

Then running:
net start mysql

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that your installation of MYSQL got corrupted. The best thing you can do is to search for MYSQL INSTALLER on your system and then run it again.

It will not download the mysql server again, it will just help you to set it up.

After that, edit your `environment variables` path and add the bin folder of your mysql to it.

By now, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have 2 different version of mysql in Windows OS and I solved the my problem by bottom step:

first stop all mysql service.

I create one config file in C:\mysqldata.cnf with bottom data(my mysql is in "C:/mysql-5.0.96-winx64" directory ):

```
[mysqld]
datadir = C:/mysql-5.0.96-winx64/data
port = 3307
```

then I run bottom command in cmd:

```
C:\mysql-5.0.96-winx64\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=C:\mysqldata.cnf --console
```

[above step reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-windows-command-line-servers.html)

then I create txt file in C:\resetpass.txt with bottom data:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password=PASSWORD('ttt') WHERE user='root';
```

then run mysqld with bottom command:

```
C:\mysql-5.0.96-winx64\bin\mysqld --init-file=C:\resetpass.txt --install mysql2 --console
net start mysql2
```

after these step you have one mysql service(with name mysql2) than run with port 3307.

I have 2 version of mysql with different user management tables(in version 5.0.96 user table difference with 5.5 version because of that I must be change table folder in first step)

you can run other mysql service with other port now(and you can run this steps with different datadir, service name and port for it again)

Answer (score 0):

1. First make sure you have installed MYsql+Sqlyog(if you are using it.).
2. - Start Registry Editor (Regedt32.exe).

- Locate the following key in the registry:

  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
  On the Edit menu, click Add Value, and then add the following registry value:

  ```
     Value Name: MaxUserPort
     Data Type: REG_DWORD
     Value: 65534
  ```

  This sets the number of ephemeral ports available to any user. The valid range is
  between 5000 and 65534 (decimal). The default value is 0x1388 (5000 decimal).

  On the Edit menu, click Add Value, and then add the following registry value:

  ```
     Value Name: TcpTimedWaitDelay
     Data Type: REG_DWORD
     Value: 30
  ```

  This sets the number of seconds to hold a TCP port connection in TIME_WAIT state before
  closing. The valid range is between 30 and 300 decimal, although you may wish to check
  with Microsoft for the latest permitted values. The default value is 0x78 (120 decimal).

  ```
  Quit Registry Editor.

  Reboot the machine.
  ```

Comment: Are you sure your answer fits to the question? To quote [TCP/IP and NBT configuration parameters for Windows XP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314053/tcp-ip-and-nbt-configuration-parameters-for-windows-xp): `There may be some unusual circumstances in customer installations where changes to certain default values are appropriate. .. Caution The Windows XP TCP/IP implementation is largely self-tuning. Adjusting registry parameters without careful study may reduce your computer's performance.`

Answer (score 0):

I will advise to use first check if my.ini exist in mysql folder in c drive or in windows folder
mysqld -install (Service successfully installed)
mysqld --initialize (no prompt)
Also another advise is not to use mysql 8, since it is not compatible with wordpress or any other opensource yet, there are lot of changes between version 5 and version 8, so if you are using mysql please use version 5.x.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to resolve the problem ->

1. Go to command prompt and at root of c (c:\ if environment variable-path is set)
   type -> `c:\>mysqld -install`.
2. Then type -> `c:\mysqld --initialize`
3. Now create one .txt file (here in our example we are taking init.txt) at root of mysql(may vary according to your directory) ->`c:\MySQL\init.txt`.
4. Now open that .txt file(init.txt) and write in it ->
   [image]

5.open Run console and write -> `Services.msc`

6.Then Services window will be open ,there select **MYSQL**,Double click It and press **start**

7.Finally open new Command prompt window and type at root of c (c:) ->`c:\>mysqlsh`
due to this shell will execute and here you are ready to go....

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u root --port 3308
```

this one help me

port number from phpmyadmin default port is 3306

[image: port number from phpmyadmin default port is 3306]