# How to get the MySQL Server Only installer package?

Tags: mysql, installation, package

I'm working on a small .Net project, I used in my project EntityFramework with  MySQL server, i tried the official Full MySQL installer, but i need only the server from that package to reduce the size of my application installer, like that used in PHPMyAdmin Installer, please show me how/where find that.

Comment: dev.mysql.com/downloads/ ? This isn't really a programming question nor is it related to 4/5 of the tags for this question

Comment: i looking for MySQL Server Only installer package

Comment: The very first one should be just the server, I believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No minimal installation is available from MySQL's site. They used to have an *essentials* version, but it's unavailable for versions >5.1.

One solution to your case is to create your own installation - it's not very complicated. The process (in general) is to include `bin`,`data`,`lib`, and `share` folders from a clean installation, run `mysqld --install`, and copy your `my.ini` file (you may need to tweak with its data folder). This can give sometimes you an installation size of about 5 MB.

Another solution will be to use MariaDB as a MySQL alternative - their [MSI](https://downloads.mariadb.org/) is about 80 MB.

Answer (score 4):

there are smaller versions, about 32.1MB it only allows you just to install the base server and configure the instance, you can use things like NAVICAT to manage it, have been using it for a lot of my .NET projects and it has been working very well

you can get it from https://filehippo.com/download_mysql/

Comment: For them that want using this way: After installation run `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe` as administrator to start the server. Also, to or run it as a service see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28642612/5318303) and my comment below it.