# Can't connect to mysql server on windows 10

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect the MySQL server (mysql-5.7.23) from command prompt using the command `mysql -u root` it throws an error `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)`.
I am using Windows 10.

I have followed following steps :

1. Unzip the mysql-5.7.23 file and put on C drive.
2. Add the `data` folder in the installation directory and also add the `my.ini`
3. Went to the `bin` folder in command prompt and executed `mysqld --initialize-insecure`, it generated some file in the `data` folder.
4. Then I added the mysql path environment variable.
5. After that I started MySQL service. It is running properly.
6. Again in the command prompt, I have executed`mysqld --install`, it shows service already exists.
7. But when I tried to connect to the server, it throws an error, `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)`

I have tried all solutions from [ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on localhost (10061)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426052/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost-10061)
, but still it is not working.

Am I missing something?

Edit : One more observation, when I execute `mysqld`, the cursor in the command prompt return to again current directory, which I think is not expected behavior.

Comment: Check the Task Manager, is the mysqld.exe is running on the Process tab?

Comment: Are you running the command prompt as admin?

Comment: firewall? (check Settings  > Update & Security  > Windows Security > Firewall & network protection)

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria yes, the mysqld.exe is running

Comment: @SiddhantSahni yes, I run the cmd as admin, but still problem is there

Comment: Try kill that process first, then run `mysqld --install`