# How to start MySQL from CMD in Laragon

Tags: mysql, batch-file, cmd, laragon

I want to write a `Batch` script to start *MySQL* on **Laragon 5.0.0** without having to follow these steps:

1. Open the Laragon App
2. *Right-Click* Start All
3. MySQL > Start MySQL

I tried

```bash
cd laragon/bin/mysql/mysql-5.7.33-winx64/bin
mysql --user=root --password=
```

I got this error

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Comment: Let's check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426052/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost-10061